# Very long (horizontaly) dropdown navigation menu jQuery issue

Tags: javascript, html, css, drop-down-menu

I'm trying to create a long dropdown nav bar. The HTML structure is the following:

```
 <div id='cssmenu'>
    <ul>
        <li><a href='#'><span>Home</span></a></li>
        <li><a href='#'><span>Products</span></a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href='#'><span>Product 1</span></a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href='#'><span>Sub Item</span></a></li>
                        <li><a href='#'><span>Sub Item</span></a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href='#'><span>Product 2</span></a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href='#'><span>Sub Item</span></a></li>
                        <li><a href='#'><span>Sub Item</span></a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href='#'><span>About</span></a></li>
        <li><a href='#'><span>Contact</span></a></li>
    </ul>
 </div>
```

Visually it looks like this, but for now,

**I'd like to add those red arrows for a horizontal scroll/slide the root `<li>` elements**:

[image]

The **demo** of navbar with css is here: http://cssmenumaker.com/builder/800017

I have searched up the web but still could not find any solutions. If somebody has some ideas please share. Thank you!

Comment: Sorry, I'm not quite sure what you're trying to achieve. Do you intend to add additional root `<li>` elements which are accessible using the arrows, or do you want to slide the entire navigation bar left and right using the arrows?

Comment: I'd like to keep a static width for the navigation bar. And if my root `<ul>` grows up (there are more `<li>`) then I want those arrows to show up, so I could scroll to those hidden `<li>` elements, and access them.

Comment: I would say try to implement a custom scrollbar on the list, like [JScrollPane](http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/), and then hide the scrollbar (`jsp.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER)`), leaving just the arrows.

Comment: hi, did you find any solution for this? I am struggling too.